How to use Google Admob rewarded video revenue model in mix with subscription model
I am developing an android app in which I am planning to use Google Admob revenue model. In all available options i want to use the mix of Rewarded video model and Subscription model. Means both the revenue model. In which i want to show the rewarded video and for subscribed users the ad will not show.
I have searched google for the documentation but of no avail.
